# How to pre download HERE Map tiles for offline usage

Tags: android, here-api

I am working on here map offline navigation. To download any country map I have to use-

```
installMapPackages(List<Integer> packageIdList)
```

I am following https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/maps-offline-maploader.html documentation for offline map.

But I need only one country map tiles for offline navigation.
Is there any way that I can download any specific country here map tiles and store it as cache in my application so that I don't need to download offline map after app installation and I can use same one.

Answer (score 0):

you should use mapLoader.getMapPackages(); to get mapping between Package Titles (country name) and Pakcage Id

> developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html

Comment: It seems like you didn't get my question. Is there any link from where I can download map tiles for any specific country without using coding and store it as cache in my app?

Comment: "without using coding" no